# Using @shareable in one subgraph and @key in another subgraph for an Apollo Federation v2.0+ supergraph

Tags: apollo-federation

Suppose that there are two subgraphs, `sub1` and `sub2`, defined for an Apollo Federation supergraph of version 2.0 or higher.
`sub1`'s schema contains:

```
#...
type MyType @shareable {
   idField: ID
   myField: String
}
#...
```

`sub2`'s schema contains:

```
#...
type MyType @key(fields:"idField") {
   idField: ID
   myField: String
}
#...
```

Is that a valid combination, or will it generate a schema composition error?